# Memory allocation in string concatenation in C#

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, string-concatenation

Let,

```
string a = “Test”;
string b = “test 2”;
string c  = a + b
```

The output of c is `"Testtest 2"`

I would like to know how is the memory allocated?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string a = "Test";
```

You create a reference called `a` and its pointing to the `"Test"` object in memory.

```
string b = "test 2";
```

You create a reference called `b` and its pointing to the `“test 2”` object in memory.

```
string c  = a + b;
```

You are allocating new memory address for `a + b` (and this process uses [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6d350wd.aspx) method.) because strings are *[immutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)* in .NET. And then `c` reference assing to this new memory address.

Here is IL code of this;

```
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldstr      "Test"
  IL_0006:  stloc.0
  IL_0007:  ldstr      "test 2"
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0
  IL_000e:  ldloc.1
  IL_000f:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0014:  stloc.2
  IL_0015:  ldloc.2
```

`stloc.0` is used, which stores the value on the top of the evaluation stack into the local memory slot 0.

`ldstr` instruction is used to load a string into the memory or evaluation stack. It is necessary to load values into evaluation stack before that can be utilized.

The `ldloc` instruction is a load local instruction. `Ldloc` places the value of a local variable on the stack.